# Count number of different name in a file

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk, wc

I want to count the number of different name in a text file of this presentation:

```
2008 girl Avah
2009 girl Avah
2008 girl Carleigh
2011 girl Kenley
2012 boy Joseph
2013 boy Joseph
2014 boy Isaac
2014 boy Brandon
```

So basically I want to skip the duplicate and have as an answer 6. I tried with `awk` to access only the third column but I can't get it to print the number of lines.

Answer (score 6):

with `awk`:

```
<fileName awk '!nameSeen[$3]++{ count++ } END{ print count }'
```

if new name found `!nameSeen[$3]++` increment counter `count++` and at the `END` print counter value.

Answer (score 6):

Since your file appears to be pre-sorted on the name column, you could use `uniq` with the `-f` (`--skip-fields`) option to output only the first line of each name, and count lines:

```
uniq -f2 FileName | wc -l
```

or

```
uniq --skip-fields=2 FileName | wc -l
```

If your data are *not* pre-sorted, you can combine `sort -u` with a `-k` field specification to achieve the same thing (although it's not clearly documented in the GNU `sort` man page):

```
sort -uk3 FileName | wc -l
```

---

It's overkill for this task, however you could also use GNU Datamash:

```
datamash -W countunique 3 < FileName
```

Comment: Does uniq not have a -c count flag?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it does - but that would count instances of each unique name rather than how many unique names there are in total

Comment: /facepalm duh I knew that

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple quick way that explains itself:

```
cat FileName | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | sed 's/\<boy\>//g' | sed 's/\<girl\>//g' | sort -u | wc -l
```

---

> **Or** to satisfy **[@αғsнιη's](https://askubuntu.com/users/283843/%CE%B1%D2%93s%D0%BD%CE%B9%CE%B7)** concern about  [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html):
>
> ```
> <FileName sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | sed 's/\<boy\>//g' | sed 's/\<girl\>//g' | sort -u | wc -l
> ```
>
> **Or** another [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) compliant command:
>
> ```
> sed 's/[0-9]*//g' <FileName | sed 's/\<boy\>//g' | sed 's/\<girl\>//g' | sort -u | wc -l
> ```

---

**A notice to [@Rebi Khalifa](https://askubuntu.com/users/1002287/rebi-khalifa):**

**[@αғsнιη](https://askubuntu.com/users/283843/%CE%B1%D2%93s%D0%BD%CE%B9%CE%B7)** **rightly** wrote in the comments below:

> or `<fileName cut -d' ' -f3 |sort -u |wc -l`; `cat filename | ...` is
>   [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)

**[@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)** **rightly** wrote in the comments below:

> I'd suggest using `cut` rather than all those `sed` commands - you
>   should at least combine them into a single invocation ex. `sed -E -e
>   's/^[0-9]+//' -e 's/\b(boy|girl)\b//'`

They both used **field selection** approach which is the **same** approach you were trying to implement to solve your issue *based on what you wrote in your question*:

> I tried with awk to access only the third column but I can't get it to
>   print the number of lines.

---

One does not need to be **sophisticated** to get things done in Ubuntu! Things can be done in many unimaginable ways.

One way which praises the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is to pipe `|` simple commands one to the next until mission is accomplished:

- Read the **content of the file** with `cat FileName` -->
- Pipe it `|` -->
- Remove **number groups** with `sed 's/[0-9]*//g'` -->
- Pipe it `|` -->
- Remove the word **boy** with `sed 's/\<boy\>//g'` -->
- Pipe it `|` -->
- Remove the word **girl** with `sed 's/\<girl\>//g'` -->
- Only **names** are left now... -->
- **Pipe it `|` -->**
- Sort the names and remove duplicates with `sort -u` -->
- Only **unique names** ar left now -->
- Pipe it `|` -->
- Count the lines with `wc -l` -->
- **Done**

Comment: or `<fileName cut -d' ' -f3 |sort -u |wc -l`; `cat filename | ...` is [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)

Comment: @αғsнιη True but using the same approach in your answer (field based). Not there is something wrong with it. Not at all, it should work fine. Only the approach is different. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest using `cut` rather than all those `sed` commands - you should at least combine them into a single invocation ex. `sed -E -e 's/^[0-9]+//' -e 's/\b(boy|girl)\b//'`

Comment: @steeldriver I strongly agree with you. But then it will not be as simple and clearly self explanatory step by step and easily customizable by understand by OP... please, read the first line (A rather simple quick way that explains itself)

Comment: In fact, I think you can do the field selection in `sort` itself i.e. `sort -uk3 FileName | wc -l`

Comment: @steeldriver That is what ( αғsнιη ) has very nicely done. This is a different approach than the field approach which is meant to give OP more options in case the sample file formatting given by OP differs from the production one. Again I agree with you 100%. Thank you. And please consider adding this as an answer for extra options if you do not mind

Answer (score 2):

A really short and easy way, using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --nidx uniq -g 3 -n input.txt
```